# How To Convert Bytes Into Strings In Go[lang]

Tags: go

I am new in Go and trying to do [Stringers](https://go.dev/tour/methods/18) exercise but I am unable to convert `bytes` to `string` in Go. I looked and found a solution `string(i[:])` but that is not working. Below is my complete code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IPAddr [4]byte

func (i IPAddr) String() string {
    // not sure how to turn bytes into string ?
   // expected result: from {127, 0, 0, 1} -> 127.0.0.1
    return string(i[:])
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
    }
}
```

expected result is

```
loopback: 127.0.0.1
googleDNS: 8.8.8.8
```

any help would be really appreciated.

CHeers,
DD.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Where should the `[` square brackets from the "expected result" come from?

Comment: If you simply delete the `String()` method you will get something similar to your expected result.

Comment: @zerkms removed `[`. I require '.' between the IP digits.
@Hymns, that is the exercise to have `String()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just output the UTF-8 encoded value as the string
the 127 take as the UTF-8 value not the string
so you should change the integer to the string first.
And in Golang integer type can not directly transform to string without function like `strconv.Itoa()` or `fmt.Sprintf('%d', int)`

your code can be like

```
func (i IPAddr) String() string {
        return return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

change `String()` to this

```golang
func (i IPAddr) String() string {
    // return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
    var res string
    res = strconv.Itoa(int(i[0]))
    for _, v := range i[1:] {
        res += "." + strconv.Itoa(int(v))
    }
    return res

// or
/*
    var sb strings.Builder

    sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(int(i[0])))

    for _, v := range i[1:] {
        sb.WriteString("." + strconv.Itoa(int(v)))
    }
    return sb.String()
*/
}
```

Comment: You could use `func (str string) Join(s []string, sep string) string`  function to join the string array.

Comment: i isn't []string

Answer (score 2):

The "right" way to convert a 4-byte array to a 'dotted quad`would be to use the in-built`net` package:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
)

func main() {
  octets     := []byte{123, 45, 67, 89}
  ip         := net.IP(octets)
  dottedQuad := ip.To4().String()

  fmt.Printf("%v is %s\n", octets, dottedQuad)

}
```

Comment: thanks, I will keep this in mind however, for this exercise I want to implement `String()`.